# (javascript) Is it possible to split an array of different object types into multiple arrays of one object type

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, mean

So I have an array that contains objects with different attributes  and I want to know how I can make multiple arrays with objects with the same attributes of the whole array.

I want to go from this

```
[
    {name:”test”, place:”country”},
    {name:”walkAndEat”, Long=100,Lat:15,Location:”place name”},
    {name:”test2”,place:”Europe”}
]
```

To

```
[
    {name:”test”, place:”country”},
    {name:”test2”,place:”Europe”}
]
[
    {name:”walkAndEat”, Long:100,Lat:15,Location:”place name”}
]
```

Comment: I corrected my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a list of objects that have different properties like so:

```
var placesOrPeople = [
    { name: 'Seymour Skinner', occupation: 'Principal' },
    { name: 'Kwik-E-Mart', lat: 23, long: 100 },
    { name: 'Sideshow Bob', occupation: 'Comic Foil' },
    { name: 'Flaming Tyre Yard', lat: 12, long: 88 },
    { name: 'Joe Quimby', occupation: 'Mayor' }
];
```

And you want them sorted into separate lists like so:

```
places = [
    { name: 'Kwik-E-Mart', lat: 23, long: 100 },
    { name: 'Flaming Tyre Yard', lat: 12, long: 88 }
];

people = [
    { name: 'Seymour Skinner', occupation: 'Principal' },
    { name: 'Sideshow Bob', occupation: 'Comic Foil' },
    { name: 'Joe Quimby', occupation: 'Mayor' }
];
```

You can use the built-in `Array.filter` command like so:

```
var places = placesOrPeople.filter(function(currentPlaceOrPerson) {
    if (currentPlaceOrPerson.occupation !== undefined) {
        // it must be a person, since locations don't have occupations
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

var people = placesOrPeople.filter(function(currentPlaceOrPerson) {
    if (currentPlaceOrPerson.lat !== undefined && currentPlaceOrPerson.long !== undefined) {
        // it must be a place, since people don't have co-ordinates
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Just be aware that you should do better object-category checks than my simple `!== undefined`. The most optimal object-category check is the approach presented by @Me.Name: creating a hash of the keys.

Answer (score 2):

If you see objects being equal as having the same properties, you can keep the keys as (stringified) indices in a collection object and check if a properties-key already exists:

```
var arrcoll = {};
function add(o){
    var keys = JSON.stringify(Object.keys(o).sort());
    var arr = arrcoll[keys];
    if(arr)
        arr.push(o);
    else
        arrcoll[keys] = [o];
    return arr;
}
```

This can be done on the fly or on a pre existing array as shown in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7foqk6v/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Objects are not set types, [they are dynamic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Dynamic_typing), meaning you can change them during execution.

> JavaScript is a loosely typed or a dynamic language. That means you don't have to declare the type of a variable ahead of time. The type will get determined automatically while the program is being processed. That also means that you can have the same variable as different types:

```
var anything = arrayOfAnyOtherType[0];
```

is valid... If you loop your source array and populate it, you can define any behavior to each object

Comment: I use Json to fill the first array(rest api) but I wan't to split the big array into different small ones because each sub array will have a different location on the screen